# Issue: Class 'CI_Config' not found in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp

I am trying to run a codeIgniter project downloaded from 1and1.co.uk ....
But when I am browsing it showing this message:

```
 An uncaught Exception was encountered
 Type: Error

Message: Class 'CI_Config' not found

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\projectname\system\core\Common.php

Line Number: 196

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\projectname\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

I dont know why?
The class is ok in system/core/config.
Its version in system/core/codeigniter is 3.1.8.

can anyone tell me the reason pls? 
Atleast some clue!

never ever faced anything like this before !

Comment: provide some more code, explain where you see this error, on which controller?

Comment: i cant show you more code cz there is nothing more than this. its in the root like http://localhost/projectname/ that means when ci is loading for initial

Comment: without seeing actual code its hard to know where actually is your issue, try to download codeigniter from https://www.codeigniter.com/download and replace with your system files, it may help

Comment: yes i know its hard but cant help ! i already changed system files but no luck !

Comment: can't help without seeing your code, you can provide application folder and I will be able to check for you

Comment: i have limitation thats why i cant send u files but u can see it through skype or team viewer if u like !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182115/discussion-between-user969068-and-m-alim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have duplicate config file also in application/core folder which was causing this issue, there should be only one config in application/config folder.